# Reset ItemNumbered

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I know there must be a simple answer to this but I've looked and looked. Suppose I form an ItemNumbered list at some point in the notebook. Then at some other point I want a new ItemNumbered list starting with number 1, but without resetting the original list. At present when I try to form the second list it always starts with n + 1, where n is the total number of items in the prior lists.

I've tried the Insert without luck. Help, please.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is subject to change in future versions of Mathematica, but for now you can use the [`CounterAssignments`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CounterAssignments.html) option to `Cell` to reset it for a particular cell, and then it applies to that cell and subsequent cells in the notebook.

Use the Option Inspector or directly edit the `Cell` expression ( *Cell* > *Show Expression* in the menu) and add the option, e.g.:

```
CounterAssignments -> {{"ItemNumbered", 1234}}
```

Note that the counter will be incremented if it is displayed in that same cell, so if you want to start numbering at 1, start your counter at 0.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I had tried executing CounterAssignments as an expression in my document without success. Using the Option Inspector worked beautifully. Thanks, again.